# calculated columns in power bi does not update results

Tags: powerbi

I created a simple dashboard and this is my first project in Power bi. I created a new column and used this formula

```
Total Records = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Table A'), View_TableEmployee[Tool Indicator]="Missing")
```

This displays the answer as 174 and 21 based on Missing/Not Missing filter selected. The numbers will eventually increase/decrease everyday.

This total records value will be displaying in "Card" visualization. I created this dashboard three days ago and displayed the results corrects when based on the filter i selected. Today, when I refreshed and dashboard again, the countrows doesnt change the number. I expect the results now to 166 and 34 based on filters selected.

Any suggestions on where I went wrong ?

Comment: Your terminology seems a little off. If you wrote a DAX formula, you were probably creating a Report (PBIX file), not a Dashboard.  Also "refresh" has many meanings in PBI - can you be more specific?

Comment: Did you schedule the refresh rate, click on the ellipsis on the power BI service (online) next to your dataset. There schedule automatic update of your data. Be aware to select the correct gateway! Personal or on-Prem!

Comment: Did you put that DAX formula in a column or a measure?

Comment: Are there any relationship between table View_TableEmployee and Table A'?

Answer (score 0):

I am just guessing what you want. Probably to achieve what you want, you need a measure, not a calculated column. Calculated columns change values only during the refresh. They are not calculated on the fly, or over-and-over.